# What is Eating My Array in Django Session?

Tags: python, django

I want to fetch 10 articles from my `Articles` model on first load and then another 10 as users scroll towards the bottom via `AJAX`. I store the ids of the first 10 in an array and then append the subsequent ones to it. This is to enable fetch articles that are not in that list but I get empty array and the first 10 articles are still fetched when I scroll to the bottom again and again.

First load:

```
import json

my_interest = user_object.interet #this returns [3,4,55,24,57]
articles = Articles.objects.all()[:10]
fetched = [x.id for x in articles]
request.session['fetched'] = json.dumps(fetched)
```

Another 10 via AJAX:

```
import operator

fetched = json.loads(request.session['fetched'])
my_interest = user_object.interet #this returns [3,4,55,24,57]

query = reduce(operator.and_,[Q(cat_id__in = my_interest ), ~Q(id__in = fetched )])
articles = Articles.objects.filter(query)[:10]

request.session['fetched'] = json.dumps( fetched + [x.id for x in articles])

context = {'articles': articles, 'fetched': request.session['fetched']}

return render_to_response('mysite/loadmore.html', context)
```

But I still get the same 10 that was first fetched repeatedly as I scroll to the bottom of the page and if I `<p> Fetched: {{fetched}} </p>` on my template I only see **Fetched:**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is your problem, but there is no need for either reduce or Q in your query. It is much simpler and clearer to write:

```
articles = Articles.objects.filter(cat_id__in=my_interest).exclude(id__in=fetched )
```

Also there's no point in dumping/loading to JSON when saving the IDs to the session. The session already takes care of serialization. Just do:

```
fetched = request.session['fetched']
...
request.session['fetched'].extend([x.id for x in articles])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Q(id__in = fetched )
```

Looks like you request articles with the same ids, that you already fetched and saved to session?

Comment: Sorry, that was supposed to be `~Q(id__in = fetched )`. I have edited it.

Comment: ok, so correct value is saved here request.session['fetched'] = json.dumps( fetched + [x.id for x in articles])? what is loaded at this line: fetched = json.loads(request.session['fetched']), is it a new value, or still from the first load?

Comment: `fetched = json.loads(request.session['fetched'])` is from old `articles`